# Can you talk about freelance projects you're working on with people other than the client?

Tags: united-states, non-disclosure, freelance

John Doe is working on a freelance writing project for Acme Inc. He has not signed an NDA. Can John talk to Jane Smith, who is not affiliated with Acme in any way, about the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The First Amendment protects the right to freedom of speech.